# Join multiple array, and return only unique elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, jquery-isotope

I have an isotope issue. I'm loading elements with ajax, and as the new elements are loaded, they have classes that are also used in filters.

I have a way of getting all the classes out of the elements by checking if the elements are in view (I'm using imagesLoaded library that checks if the images are loaded, and then to that I have used `.bind('inview',...` that will trigger the change so that I can get my array of classes out).

```
$('#container').find('article').each(function(){
     var class_list = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
});
```

This will return an array of classes on my loaded objects like:

```
["class1", "class2", "class3", ""]
```

And I get several of those. Now how do I take all those, create a new array and check to see if they are unique?

I found `.unique()` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/, and .concat() that should create the array, but I don't know how to target them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of each class as a jQuery collection all in a `Array.filter` method:

```
$('#container').find('article').each(function(){
     var class_list = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);

     var uniqueClasses = class_list.filter(function(className) {
         return className && $("." + className).length === 1;
     });
});
```

Comment: This seems to do this, but for some reason it deletes the classes on ajax load.

Comment: Are you over-writing them in your AJAX call?

Comment: No, nothing in my AJAX handles this with classes. Just simple return of the articles.

Comment: Not sure why your classes would be disappearing then?

Comment: Me either :S Maybe it's the imagesLoaded. But thanks for the help. I'll go from there :)